# how to create unique index only for inner object and not on the whole collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a Person bson:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 35,
  "kids": [
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "age": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "tina",
      "age": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

a preson have list of kids as you can see, and I dont want to allow insertion of a person with same kid names. and also not person with the same name.

so I added index for `"name"` and for `"kids.name"`, but this will not allow to ha have kids with the same name at all...

so now this will not be allowed:

```
{
  "name": "Mary",
  "age": 33,
  "kids": [
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "age": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "ron",
      "age": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

but I want to be able to insert different person name with a kid name that is already exists.

so how can I make kid name to be unique only in the same person object?

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement, you need to create one compound index instead of two separate indexes to achieve this.

See [MongoDB compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/index.html) for information about compound indexes.

For example:

```
> db.test.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5b3afb61bb700c264fcfb8d3"),
  "name": "John",
  "age": 35,
  "kids": [
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "age": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "tina",
      "age": 3
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5b3afb6bbb700c264fcfb8d4"),
  "name": "Mary",
  "age": 33,
  "kids": [
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "age": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "ron",
      "age": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Creating this compound index will achieve what you require:

```
> db.test.createIndex({name:1, 'kids.name':1}, {unique:true})
{
  "createdCollectionAutomatically": false,
  "numIndexesBefore": 1,
  "numIndexesAfter": 2,
  "ok": 1
}
```

However creating a unique index on `kids.name` will not work because both `John` and `Mary` has a kid named `tom`:

```
> db.test.createIndex({'kids.name':1}, {unique:true})
{
  "operationTime": Timestamp(1530592138, 1),
  "ok": 0,
  "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: kids.name_1 dup key: { : \"tom\" }",
  "code": 11000,
  "codeName": "DuplicateKey"
}
```

In terms of this specific index, see related MongoDB indexes resources and especially:

- [Unique Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/)
- [Multikey Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/index.html)

because in this example, the index is a **compound-multikey-unique index**.

That is:

- The combination of every single `name` + `kids.name` must be unique in the collection (**unique index restriction**)
- The index would not help with sorting based on `kids.name`, but can help sorting based on `name` (**compound index restriction**)
- The index will enumerate and create one index entry per `name` + `kids.name` combination (**multikey index restriction**)

In other words, this index will not allow anyone else named `John` with a kid named either `tom` or `tina` into the collection anymore.

Comment: i think maybe you understand me wrong, cause tina and john suppose to be able to have kid name "tom". that is what I want. i want john to NOT be able to create two kids name "tom", but other people can have a "tom" kid...

Comment: the compound index will help restrict it so john and mary wont be able to have kid name "tom"

Comment: The unique compound index will ensure the **combination** of `name + kid.name` to be unique. That is, `John` cannot have two kids named `tom`, but it **will** allow `Mary` to have a kid named `tom`. Have you actually tried the solution I wrote in my reply?